# Can't get values of select and reassign it

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a react project and I want to get the current values of two selectors and reassign their values to different states : `this.state.sliderMaxSelected` and `this.state.sliderMinSelected` but they are never updated. Why?

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';



export default class PureDynamicSlider extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            sliderMinSelected: 0,
            sliderMaxSelected: 10
        };
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return this.props.min !== nextProps.min ||
         this.props.max !== nextProps.max;
    }


    _handleChangeSliderMin(e){
        console.log("min")
        console.log(e.target.value)
        this.setState({sliderMinSelected: e.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.sliderMinSelected)
    }

    _handleChangeSliderMax(e){
        console.log("max")
        console.log(e.target.value)
        this.setState({sliderMaxSelected: e.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.sliderMaxSelected)
    }

    render() {
        const {min,max} = this.props;

        var sliderMinList = [0,1];

        var sliderMinValues =[];

        var sliderMaxList = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

        var sliderMaxValues =[];

        for (var index in sliderMinList) {
            sliderMinValues.push(<option key={index} value={sliderMinList[index]}>{"Valeur "+sliderMinList[index]}</option>);
        }

        for (var index in sliderMaxList) {
            sliderMaxValues.push(<option key={index} value={sliderMaxList[index]}>{"Valeur "+sliderMaxList[index]}</option>);
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <select className="form-control" id="select1"
                        value={this.state.sliderMinSelected} onChange={this._handleChangeSliderMin.bind(this)}
                     >
                    {sliderMinValues}
                </select>
                <p>{this.state.sliderMinSelected}</p>
                <select className="form-control" id="select1"
                        value={this.state.sliderMaxSelected} onChange={this._handleChangeSliderMax}
                   >
                    {sliderMaxValues}
                </select>
                <p>{this.state.sliderMaxSelected}</p>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: pls try `onChange={this._handleChangeSliderMax}` to `onChange={this._handleChangeSliderMax.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  _handleChangeSliderMin(e){
        console.log("min")
        console.log(e.target.value)//You will get the value
        this.setState({sliderMinSelected: e.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.sliderMinSelected)//You will get undefined value
    }

    _handleChangeSliderMax(e){
        console.log("max")
        console.log(e.target.value)// you will get the value
        this.setState({sliderMaxSelected: e.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.sliderMaxSelected)////You will get undefined value
}
```

This reason is, as soon as setState if fired, DOM is re-rendered. So, you can't get the update value.

So, if you want to view the updated state, console it inside render.

```
 render() {
  if(this.state.sliderMaxSelected)
  console.log(this.state.sliderMaxSelected);
}
```

EDIT1 :Change to

```
    <select className="form-control" id="select1"
       value={this.state.sliderMaxSelected} onChange={this._handleChangeSliderMax.bind(this)}>
   {sliderMaxValues }
   </select>
```